# Kafka Producer stops my code

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, kafka-python

I'm calling a function which sends some data from kafka producer, but after it sends I'm returning a response which doesn't return. The code gets stuck at return. Anyone any idea whats happening?

My code is as follows,

```
def postEvent(eventData):
    print("The eventData is...",eventData)
    timestamp = datetime.now().__format__("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    try:
        producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=["host:port"])
        data = json.dumps(eventData).encode('utf-8')
        try:

            kafkaResponse = producer.send('streamTest', data)

            response ={'time': str(timestamp), 'kafkaResponse':kafkaResponse.get(), 
                       'postResult': 'true'}
            print('kafaka response is...', response)
        except ConnectionAbortedError:
                response ={'time': str(timestamp), 'postResult': 'false'}
        except kafka.errors.KafkaTimeoutError:
                response ={'time': str(timestamp), 'postResult': 'false'}
        print('kafaka response is...', response)
        return response
    except kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable:
        response = {'Response':'Kafka Errors... NoBrokersAvailable'}
        print('kafaka response ', response)
        return response
```

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your question which `return` statement it's hanging at.

I tested your code, and it worked perfectly for me with a Kafka 0.10.0.1 broker and `kafka-python` 1.3.5.

It's probably a Kafka cluster networking issue, so the two places you are likely to hang are either:
1. `kafkaResponse.get()` while you wait for the `Future` to resolve
2. No brokers available, while the brokers timeout. If you pass in multiple brokers, keep in mind that they will need to each timeout before it throws the `NoBrokersAvailable` error.